# C - erroneous output after multiplication of large numbers

Tags: c, double, multiplication

I'm implementing my own decrease-and-conquer method for a<sup>n</sup>.

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double dncpow(int a, int n)
{
    double p = 1.0;
    if(n != 0)
    {
        p = dncpow(a, n / 2);
        p = p * p;
        if(n % 2)
        {
            p = p * (double)a;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int n;
    int a_upper = 10;
    int n_upper = 50;
    int times = 5;
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    for(int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    {
        a = rand() % a_upper;
        n = rand() % n_upper;
        printf("a = %d, n = %d\n", a, n);
        printf("pow = %.0f\ndnc = %.0f\n\n", pow(a, n), dncpow(a, n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code works for small values of a and n, but a mismatch in the output of pow() and dncpow() is observed for inputs such as:

a = 7, n = 39

pow = 909543680129861204865300750663680

dnc = 909543680129861348980488826519552

I'm pretty sure that the algorithm is correct, but dncpow() is giving me wrong answers.
Can someone please help me rectify this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That number might be too big for `double` http://ideone.com/sq95lz

Comment: Note that `dncpow(int a, int n)` fails for `dncpow(a, some_negative)`

Comment: `double` has precision of typically about 16 decimal digits and the 2 results are within that precision.  Do you expect a number like `9e38-ish`, a 100+ bit number to be encoded exactly in a `double` which is typically 64 bits?

Comment: @chux, I'm getting similar outputs upon replacing 'double' with 'long long'. The latter is supposed to be stored exactly, isn't it?

Comment: These numbers are outside the minimum range requirements for long long -- maybe your implementation has an unusually large range?   In any case, pow() returns a double, not a long long, so the precision issue that chux mentioned is still an issue

Comment: What is your motivation for using a binary floating point type in order to solve a problem describable in integer arithmetic?

Comment: "I'm getting similar outputs upon replacing 'double' with 'long long'. " --> and what was that output?  For debug purposes, delete `srand(time(&t))` to provide consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that, these numbers are too large for what your computer can represent exactly in a single variable. With a floating point type, there's an exponent stored separately and therefore it's still possible to represent a number *near* the real number, dropping the lowest bits of the mantissa.

Regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778296/c-erroneous-output-after-multiplication-of-large-numbers#comment78515820_45778296):

> I'm getting similar outputs upon replacing 'double' with 'long long'. The latter is supposed to be stored exactly, isn't it?

- If you call a function taking `double`, it won't *magically* operate on `long long` instead. Your value is simply converted to `double` and you'll just get the same result.
- Even with a function handling `long long` (which has 64 bits on nowadays' typical platforms), you can't deal with such large numbers. 64 bits aren't enough to store them. With an *unsigned* integer type, they will just "wrap around" to `0` on overflow. With a *signed* integer type, the behavior of overflow is **undefined** (but still somewhat likely a wrap around). So you'll get some number that has absolutely nothing to do with your expected result. That's arguably worse than the result with a floating point type, that's just *not precise*.

For exact calculations on large numbers, the only way is to store them in an *array* (typically of unsigned integers like `uintmax_t`) and implement all the arithmetics yourself. That's a nice exercise, and a **lot** of work, especially when performance is of interest (the "naive" arithmetic algorithms are typically very inefficient).

For some real-life program, you won't reinvent the wheel here, as there are libraries for handling large numbers. The arguably best known is [libgmp](https://gmplib.org/). Read the manuals there and use it.

Comment: It may be worth mention that, with 64 bit `long long`, `LLONG_MAX` is about 9e18, which is just a bit smaller than 7e39.

Comment: "a bit" ... nice ;)